# Digital Rupee and it's URI parameters

Tags: payment

Let me admit that Digital Rupee aka ***e***₹ is  still under pilot phase. However, as I got a chance to join the survey program through my bank app, I found this CBDC system not only supports Deeplinking but also it has some enhanced features compared to UPI URI but has some serious downsides too.

Ok, as I generated my profile QR and a Collect QR, I found ***e***₹ supports two basic methods (let me call them by this phase) `pay` and `collect`.

While the URI is `DigitalRupee`, the methods actually support dynamic payments under following parameters (parameters which are identical to UPI are in first part of the table):

| Parameter | Desc (As I understand ) |
| --- | --- |
| pa | walletaddress @ somekindofbankname |
| pn | person name |
| cu | Currency |
| am | amount |
| ---------- | ----------------------- |
| QRts | QR creation time stamp Date + Time + Timezone |
| QRexpires | 15 minutes for expiry (appears in `collect` QR only, not in `pay` QR) |
| mode | ? |
| orgid | ? |
| ver | ? |
| qrMedium | ? |

Until now collect request with expiry in UPI ecosystem can only be made by Payment Gateways, not open to anyone. But with ***e***₹ it may give us immense flexibility in accepting payments.

Now my Questions are:

1. Where from I get to know about all of its parameters ? If no manual is there till now, can anyone working in this field help?
2. `collect` and `pay` both use `pa` as some cryptic text followed by `@` followed by bank identity handle, like `sbi`, `hdfcbank` etc. Typically in URI environment `collect` request also contains the information from whom it should be collected. But here it is seemingly absent but it's giving the feature for expiry which can be coded and QRed. Does there exists some notion of providing collected address too.
3. Although it is helpful in its niche environment, ***e***₹ as they say has no option to communicate directly with bank. That is like UPI I cannot transfer money to an Bank Account number. In UPI system that was provided by the regular expression `<AccNo>@<IFSC>.ifsc.npci` to the parameter `pa`. Does there exist a way to include direct bank transfer too?
4. Does there exist `mam` parameter i.e. minimum amount to pay/collect or `tn` i.e. transaction note? Those are very useful in UPI.